# Inactive Segment - How to Select Subscribers with No Clicks before a set date

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, query, dataextensions

I'm trying to identify email subscribers from within a specified data extension who have not clicked since 2/1/2013, but my query isn't working.

I posted a similar topic yesterday, and received some great info, so I'm hoping that if someone here has a free second today, I could get some advice on my query.

```
SELECT b.Email
FROM BRAND_PREPOLICY b
JOIN _Click c
    ON c.SubscriberID = b.Email
WHERE c.EventDate < '2013-3-1'
```

I want this query to say: *From the data extension titled BRAND_PREPOLICY, give me all email addresses that haven't clicked since before 3/1/2013.  Email address (field name = Email) is set as the subscriber key for the BRAND_PREPOLICY data extension.*

I've tried a few tweaks, but I can't figure out why my resulting data extension is showing up empty after I run this query.  We definitely had clicks in *ET before 3/1/2013*.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post a sample of the EventDate column from _Click? If it is a Datetime column, I'm inclined to think that you may need to change the statement to: SELECT b.Email FROM BRAND_PREPOLICY b JOIN _Click c ON c.SubscriberID = b.Email WHERE c.EventDate < '2013-3-1T00:00:00Z'

Answer (score 1):

System Data Views such as _Click only go back 6 months.

Source: http://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/query_activity/

Answer (score 1):

Mac is correct, the contents of the system data views only go back 6 months.  To access click data older than this, you would need to preform a [tracking extract](http://wiki.memberlandingpages.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/data_extract_activity/).  You could theoretically extract the data; import in a data extension; and then modify your query to reference the new data extension.  However if you are needing to retrieve 2+ years of click activity (2013-3-1), you might be better off processing this data offline.